# Trying to get a referenced vb.net dll to showdialog in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll, showdialog

I've got a legacy vb.net dll referenced in my c# project.
calling the various methods no problem, but I need to be able to display a form from the dll, so users can pick the right line from a database response.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("FMSValidation.dll");
```

produces no error, but

```
Type   type  = assembly.GetType (FMSValidation.CreditorDetails );
```

tells me 'CreditorDetails' is a type, which is not valid in the context.

Answer (score 3):

`assembly.GetType` does not accept an actual type. It accepts a string:

```
Type type = assembly.GetType("FMSValidation.CreditorDetails");
```

It wouldn't make sense for `assembly.GetType` to be able to take a type, since at that point you already have a type.

Once you have a type, you can create an instance of it with the activator class:

```
var form = (System.Windows.Forms.Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
form.ShowDialog();
```

If `CreditorDetails` requires any constructor arguments, use an overload of `CreateInstance` that accepts the array of arguments.

---

It seems like the compiler knows `FMSValidation.CreditorDetails` is a type - so I wonder why you are dynamically loading the assembly and trying to use GetType at all. You should just be able to add a reference to the assembly and use its types like you would any other, like `new FMSValidation.CreditorDetails()`.

Comment: I can, but I'm trying to get the dll to launch a window, which it seems reluctant to do.

Comment: That works to the point of not causing an error, but I can't use  'LoadFile' as I don't actually know where the dll is (it's complicated). Is there a way to get 'showdialog' to work with the type?

Answer (score 0):

`FMSValidation.CreditorDetails` is a type, but it is not an actual `Type` object. If you want an actual type object, and you can write the name of the type in your source code (ie. it's not in a string variable or something) then you would use `typeof(FMSValidation.CreditorDetails)` instead of `assembly.GetType`.